# How to copy iphone contacts into a csv file

Tags: iphone, csv

I want to copy my contacts in a csv file and then later on I want to use them with another icloud account by importing the contacts. I am using ubuntu version 17.10,mobile iphone se Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What application do you use currently to manage your contacts in Ubuntu?

Comment: i used nothing to operate contacts in ubuntu

Comment: Then please [edit] the question to clarify the current situation: where are the contacts currently stored and in what format?

Comment: HI @DavidFoerster currently I haven't used any way to store my contacts.. I have my contacts in iphone n I want to use those contacts when I connect to another iphone with another account can I achieve like that?

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: You can try [this procedure](/a/919473/175814) to at least extract the current contact list. Then you may be able to import it into an iCloud account through some other means.

Answer (score 0):

**Use iPhone-app for contacts exporting to csv/vcf-file, then share with/copy to your cloud-app**

Search in the Apple App Store for "backup contacts csv" and you will find many apps providing csv- & vcf-file export of your ipohne contacts. Free apps are good enough, no need to spend money.

The apps create csv- &/or vcf-files and provide standard iphone share methods to copy them to your favorite cloud-app (e.g. tresorit, file explorer, dropbox, icloud, etc.). From there the files are available for any operation system. Personally, I just used the app ["Backup Contacts To VCF And CSV"](https://www.148apps.com/app/1463503834/) without investigating the best app - worked!

So if it's only about exporting your iphone contacts, there's no need to install Windows+iTunes on a VirtualBox or other time consuming workarounds...